# Homebrew install g++ 4.7 not working

Tags: c++, macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite

all over the internet you can find explanations where people forget to mention something.
Could you please give me a **complete** explanation on how to install g++ 4.7 on my os x yosemite?
I used the following commands:

1)
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

2)
brew tap homebrew/versions

3)
brew install gcc47

Seems to have worked according to the success messages.
And still, the program that I want to install (which needs g++ 4.7 or higher) fails because there is no g++ 4.7

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found the answer. It is: Don't use homebrew :-P

This worked for me:
Install macports, i.e. download the .pkg file from the homepage, double-click it and say yes yes yes, confirm, yes agree credit card yes np, confirm, ok ok ok, cya

Then start a terminal (If you had one opened before the macports install you need to restart it!)

Then use these commands:

sudo port selfupdate

sudo port install gcc47

sudo port select --set gcc mp-gcc47